# export tableau view to pdf after applying filter in TSC

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to export a tableau view using python tableau server client.

Following is the part of code which is used for creating pdf.

```
server.views.populate_pdf(view, options)

with file("dashboard.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(view.pdf)
```

This code is working fine and it is exporting a view to pdf file.

My tableau dashboard has few filters(e.g. product_type, vendor).

How can I add a view filter while exporting so that I will only get data for specific product_type and vendor?

Comment: Hi, what value do you set to view ?? can you give me an example?

Comment: hi @BC1554, most of the values set while exporting view are mentioned in the answer, but if you are talking about values that are set while creating view on tableau I am not aware about it. View was created by different team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer using following example.
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/export.py
We need to add view filters(vf) as follow:

```
option_factory = getattr(TSC, "PDFRequestOptions")
options = option_factory().vf("product_type","Handphone")
options.vf("vendor","vendor1")

#In case of multi select filter we can use coma separated values as followed
options.vf("vendor","vendor1,vendor2")
#To get the list of all filter options use
print options.view_filters
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/tableauserverclient/server/request_options.py#L90

Once we have filter options ready we can pass it to populate pdf.

```
server.views.populate_pdf(view, options)
with file("dashboard.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(view.pdf)
```