# Return all possible filter values with tableau server client for python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am using the Tableau Server REST API via the python server client library (https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python) to automatically download pdf versions of several tableau workbook views.

For each pdf export I am filtering the Tableau view according to set parameter values. Currently, all possible parameter values are specified manually but I would like to instead find all possible options and loop over those (generating one pdf per filter option). Is that possible?

A small example code where a tableau view is filtered on the parameter country and possible values "Sweden" and "Norway":

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC 

Parameters = [{"Parameter Name" : "Country", "ParameterValue" : "Sweden"}, 
              {"Parameter Name" : "Country", "ParameterValue" : "Norway"}]

for params in Parameters:
      image_req_options = TSC.PDFRequestOptions()
      image_req_options.vf(params["ParameterName"], params["ParameterValue"]

      server.views.populate_pdf(view, image_req_options)
      with open('output_pdf_{}.pdf'.format(params["ParameterValue"]), 'wb') as f:
           f.write(view.pdf)
```

Instead of defining the Parameters list of dictionaries I would like to find all possible ParameterValues for the Parameter Country.

Comment: Tableau workbooks are XMLs so you can open one in a text editor. If you download the workbook, convert to XML, then parse it with Element Tree, you could extract the parameter values. I don't have a specific example for this but did write this up recently where I extracted the data sources. http://dataknightrises.com/2020/09/14/power-tools-to-the-people/

Comment: I believe this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857569/11273249

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with by creating a separate private workbook using the same published datasource and underlying filters, then using the ViewItem class method `populate_csv` to return the values required. You will **not** be able to return *hardcoded parameters*, but you could use *dynamic parameters* loaded from a dimension field. [Learn more about dynamic parameters here.](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm)

The `populate_csv` function returns the same data as the "Download Crosstab" option from Tableau Cloud, selecting the first option that appears on a view based on alphabetical order.

1. Make sure your workbook's parameters are generated from a dimension field
2. Create and publish a new view: drop your dimension you want to filter on on 'rows', and nothing else. It will look like an empty crosstab.
3. Extract row values into `pandas` `DataFrame` object.

```
import tempfile
import pandas as pd

new_view_id = "view_id_string_here"

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(your_auth)
server = TSC.Server(your_server)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    view = server.views.get_by_id(new_view_id)
    server.views.populate_csv(view)
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as file:
        for chunk in view.csv:
            file.write(chunk)
        file.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

This dataframe should contain all dimension values in the default view of the view you created and published. You can use this as you require.